# Find out which application is accessing Location Services in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, location-services

After the latest Windows 10 update, the "location services" icon in the taskbar is constantly on.

I have manually disabled all applications from accessing my location via the settings menu and thus have only allowed non-application processes to access location services (things like Windows time zone checker).

However, the icon remains constantly on, even with Windows time zone checking disabled, which makes me wonder:

## How can you see which processes are currently accessing location services?

Comment: There is a service called  "Geolocation Service" Service name::lfsvc. Check if it running in Services.msc.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but I was experiencing the same issue. 
 I contacted Microsoft and was advised that the issue is resolved in the latest build.  I updated from version 1709, build 16299.431 to 16299.547, and the issue was resolved for me.  Location services isn't mentioned directly in the patch notes, but time zone information is - https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4338825/windows-10-update-kb4338825